# rsync last 3 days plus weekly backups

Tags: cron, rsync, incremental-backup

I have a shell script that i'll be running with a crontab. Basically I want to modify this so I can do daily backups for the last 3 days. I've seen examples where the last 7 days are backup. I just need the last 3 rolling days. I know I would have to do a separate script for the weekly schedule.

code:

```
rsync -avzh --delete XXXX@XXXXX:/home/XXXXX/source/ /$HOME/destination
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

Someone has already written a script that does this, and it has a lot of great features, plus it has been tested by many people for years.  It is called "rsnapshot".

I highly recommend "rsnapshot".  It is easy to configure and will do a 3-day retention, or even more complex retention policies.

http://www.rsnapshot.org/

Comment: I will investigate on this. So that means that you can't do this with rsync? will rsnapshot work with crontab?

Comment: To be clear, rsnapshot is just a script that calls rsync.  It just does all the complexities of expiring old snapshots for you.

Comment: I see, does this work on ubuntu? is not listed in their website

Comment: @ReneMerino It works perfectly fine on Debian, which is still pretty close to Ubuntu. Why don't you try it yourself? Just use a smaller dataset if you want to speed things up while you're testing.

Comment: I installed it in my server, I hope this works - Thanks @TomOnTime

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you also want to take a look at http://backuppc.sourceforge.net/

It's more than just a script, it's a server side solution for backing up multiple servers. Maybe a bit too much for you, but also very popular.